# How do I check for availability of a symbol, rather than OS version, in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, api, swift3, api-versioning

I have code of the form

```
if #available(iOS 10.2, *) {
    device = AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInDualCamera
} else {
    device = AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInDuoCamera
}
```

Is

```
if #available(AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInDualCamera) {
```

... possible?

The latter expresses my intention better — if the value `builtInDualCamera` exists, use it. I couldn't care less whether it was introduced in iOS 10.1 or .2 or .3.

Comment: Maybe `responds(to: Selector)`?

Comment: See https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/64332

Comment: It's a constant, not a method, so respondsToSelector doesn't work.

Comment: For better or worse, that isn't the way Apple has done it;  you need to check for the app version rather than a specific symbol.